# What happens when you do not place an icon in all possible sizes in your res folder?

Tags: android, image, scaling

I am wondering what would happen if you put for instance one image in only one specific size, let's say image X in `hdpi` and an other image Y in only resolution size `xxhdpi`, the size which was "right" for the device was `xhdpi`. Assuming that the OS decided what was the "right" size for the device.

Will it then downscale the image `xxhdpi` and upscale `hdpi` to `xhdpi`? Or would it only change the size of one image, for instance the one with the lowest resolution remains the same, the higher ones are downscaled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite an interesting question out there!

In this case, the bigger drawable will be taken an downscaled to the device needs.
However, if the device is i.e. xxhdpi and you provide drawables ie. for mdpi and hdpi, the OS will take the hdpi drawable and scale it UP.

Answer (score 1):

Android chooses the one appropriate for the resolution or screen dimensions. ..when it doesn't find one in the right folde than it goes down in the resolution searching for a lower quality folder...again when it doesn't find one in the folder with lower resolutions than it searches in the higher quality....and crashes if there is also none at runtime....AT compiletime you'll get error when thers n no image

Depends on how you display the images....Icons get everytime up or down scaled. ...IT is recommended that you have one and only one xxxhdpi icon in your app because downscaling is better than up scaling due to AA

Comment: Why is it recommended to only have 1 xxxhdpi? why not 0?

Comment: I mean the app launcher icon sry  it must be for performance reasons in the mipmap folder BTW not in the res folder

Comment: Ok thank you. The mipmap folder is a child folder though but I think I understand what you mean.

Comment: Doesn't matter you don't put it in the normal res folders if you want to get performance boost